# Google Cloud Logging in Python - ImportError

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I get the following error when trying to import Google Cloud Logging in Python:

```
from google.cloud import logging
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from google.cloud.logging.client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/client.py", line 32, in <module>
    from google.cloud.client import ClientWithProject
ImportError: cannot import name 'ClientWithProject'
```

I have it running in a virtual environment
with this in requirements.txt:

```
google-cloud-logging>=0.20.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get to the next error with:

> pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-logging

for Python 3 and:

> pip install --upgrade google-cloud-logging

for Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your google cloud components, run in terminal as admin:

```
 gcloud components update
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install dataproc on top of the google-cloud-logging and google-cloud-storage.

Python3
`pip3 install mrjob google-cloud-dataproc google-cloud-logging google-cloud-storage`

Python2.7
`pip3 install mrjob google-cloud-dataproc google-cloud-logging google-cloud-storage`